# CSS how to Scale and Aspect Ratio width based on height?

Tags: html, css

assume the height is 80% of parent div, and I want the width is twice the height. so can I do this :

.scal{
height:'80%',
width:2 x height
}

can it be possible or I have another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking can be achieved in CSS provided you know the height of the parent element

#### CSS

```
width: calc(whateverElementsHeightInUnits * 2)
```

However I think the best way to do this is with jQuery as below

#### Jquery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $('.scal').css({ width: $(whateverElement).innerHeight() * 2 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something approaching this using a combination of [CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function:

```css
:root {
  --rect-height: 100px;
}

.rect {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  height: var(--rect-height);
  width: calc(var(--rect-height) * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Height of 80% you could write calc(var(--rect-height) * 0.8);

Comment: @AlexHawking Yeah, you might be correct-- I tried to be general because I wasn't _completely_ certain I understood the entirety of the poster's question, but it seemed likely that these pieces would get them what they needed.  You might be understanding something I am not from their post.

Comment: Haha your answer was correct but he said something about using 80% of the height and multiplying by 0.8 will give you 80%